# how to remove ffmpeg ? and install again

Tags: terminal, command-line

I want to remove ffmpeg. Typed to terminal

```
    ..........$ rm ffmpeg
    rm: ffmpeg: is a directory
    ..........$ ffmpeg
    ffmpeg version 2.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 28 2014 01:43:39 with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79)     (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.100 / 55. 49.100
  libavformat    55. 26.100 / 55. 26.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  1.101 /  4.  1.101
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
  usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options]     outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
```

How do I remove and install it again?

I finally got this

```
.........$ which ffmpeg
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg
```

Comment: How did you install `ffmpeg`? Did you use a package manager like home brew or MacPorts? Maybe a pre-packaged installer pkg?

Comment: yes I have brew.but I could not remove ffmpeg.

Comment: Sadly no configuration information in the output. Use brew to install a new copy of `ffmpeg`. If brew is set up correctly, `brew doctor`, the latest brew edition of `ffmpeg` will override any older copies.

Comment: Where is ffmpeg - try `which ffmpeg`

Comment: @mark it is done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Removal

If you installed with [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh), the following Terminal.app command will perform the uninstall:

```
brew uninstall ffmpeg
```

If you are not sure how you installed `ffmpeg`, try running the command alone. The output will include a line containing the binary's location on your Mac:

```
ffmpeg
```

Look for output similar to:

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov 21 2013 11:36:01 with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.4 …
```

The key information in this extract is `/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/`; this provides the location and that `ffmpeg` was installed as a HomeBrew Cellar.

If you do not see this output or it does not mention Cellar, please expand your question with the output you do see.

### Alternative Installations

It is critical to know how you installed `ffmpeg` in order to know how to remove it. If may just be removing a folder, or it may be hunting around in `/usr/local/` and `/usr/bin` folders for installed binaries.

Easy removal and upgrading is a strong argument for using a package manager for command line tools. Well supported package managers on the Mac include brew and MacPorts.

### Re-installation

To install `ffmpeg` again, after removing the prior version, use brew to handle the entire process with:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Comment: it does not uninstall when I type brew uninstall ffmpeg.dhcp-31-66:~ samirebalta$ ffmpeg
ffmpeg version 2.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 28 2014 01:43:39 with Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
  configuration: 
 ...
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
usage: ffmpeg [options] [[infile options] -i infile]... {[outfile options] outfile}...

Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'

what can I do now?

Comment: Please can you expand your question with the complete output you do see from `ffmpeg`. The content after `configuration:` is key.

Comment: thnx I expanded

Comment: Please can you try @Mark suggestion of `which ffmpeg` and append the output to your answer.